# openSSL C program

Tags: c, ssl

I wrote a program to send the contents of a file between a computer and a raspberry pi 4; on localhost it works but when I try it between the two hosts it does not work.
The output is "Send Success, NumBytes = 7" from the sender part and "Receive Success, NumBytes = 0" from the receiver part.
I created the certificate following this guide: https://www.simba.com/products/SEN/doc/Client-Server_user_guide/content/clientserver/configuringssl/signingca.htm

sender.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <libgen.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include "transfer.h"
#include <openssl/ssl.h>

void sendfile(FILE *fp, SSL *ssl);
ssize_t total = 0;
SSL_CTX *ctx;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SSL *ssl;
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        perror("usage:send_file filepath <IPaddress>");
        exit(1);
    }

    SSL_library_init();

    int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0)
    {
        perror("Can't allocate sockfd");
        exit(1);
    }

    if ((ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method())) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: failed to create SSL_CTX\n");
        return -1;
    }
    SSL_CTX_set_options(ctx,SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1_3);

    if (SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx, "./certs/CA-cert.pem", 0) != 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error loading ./certs/cacert.pem, please check the file.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    struct sockaddr_in serveraddr;
    memset(&serveraddr, 0, sizeof(serveraddr));
    serveraddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serveraddr.sin_port = htons(SERVERPORT);
    if (inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[2], &serveraddr.sin_addr) < 0)
    {
        perror("IPaddress Convert Error");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (connect(sockfd, (const struct sockaddr *)&serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr)) < 0)
    {
        perror("Connect Error");
        exit(1);
    }

    if ((ssl = SSL_new(ctx)) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: failed to create SSL object\n");
        return -1;
    }

    /* Attach SSL to the socket */
    SSL_set_fd(ssl, sockfd);
    /* Connect to SSL on the server side */
    if (SSL_connect(ssl) < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: failed to connect to SSL\n");
        return -1;
    }

    
    char *filename = basename(argv[1]);
    if (filename == NULL)
    {
        perror("Can't get filename");
        exit(1);
    }

    char buff[BUFFSIZE] = {0};
    strncpy(buff, filename, strlen(filename));
    if (send(sockfd, buff, BUFFSIZE, 0) == -1)
    {
        perror("Can't send filename");
        exit(1);
    }

    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        perror("Can't open file");
        exit(1);
    }

    sendfile(fp, ssl);
    //puts("Send Success");
    printf("Send Success, NumBytes = %d\n", total);
    fclose(fp);
    close(sockfd);
    SSL_free(ssl);
    SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
    return 0;
}

void sendfile(FILE *fp, SSL *ssl)
{
    int n;
    char sendline[MAX_LINE] = {0};
    while ((n = fread(sendline, sizeof(char), MAX_LINE, fp)) > 0)
    {
        total += n;
        if (n != MAX_LINE && ferror(fp))
        {
            perror("Read File Error");
            exit(1);
        }
        if (SSL_write(ssl, sendline, strlen(sendline)) <= 0)
        {
            perror("Can't send file\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        memset(sendline, 0, MAX_LINE);  
    }
}
```

receiver.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include "transfer.h"
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
void writefile(SSL *ssl, FILE *fp);
ssize_t total = 0;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SSL_CTX *ctx;
    SSL *ssl;
    SSL_library_init();
    int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd == -1)
    {
        perror("Can't allocate sockfd");
        exit(1);
    }
    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_method());
    SSL_CTX_set_options(ctx, SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3);
    if (ctx == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: failed to create SSL_CTX\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if (SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx, "./certs/CA-cert.pem", 0) != 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error loading ./certs/ca-cert.pem, please check the file.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if (SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ctx, "./certs/server-cert.pem", SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) != 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error loading ./certs/servercert.pem, please check the file.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if (SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx, "./certs/server-key.pem", SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) != 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error loading ./certs/serverkey.pem, please check the file.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    //SSL_CTX_set_options(ctx,SSL_OP_NO_TICKET);

    struct sockaddr_in clientaddr, serveraddr;
    memset(&serveraddr, 0, sizeof(serveraddr));
    serveraddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    serveraddr.sin_port = htons(SERVERPORT);

    if (bind(sockfd, (const struct sockaddr *)&serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr)) == -1)
    {
        perror("Bind Error");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (listen(sockfd, LINSTENPORT) == -1)
    {
        perror("Listen Error");
        exit(1);
    }

    socklen_t addrlen = sizeof(clientaddr);
    int connfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&clientaddr, &addrlen);
    if (connfd == -1)
    {
        perror("Connect Error");
        exit(1);
    }
    close(sockfd);

    if ((ssl = SSL_new(ctx)) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: failed to create SSL object\n");
        return -1;
    }
    SSL_set_fd(ssl, connfd);

    /* Establish TLS connection */
    int ret = SSL_accept(ssl);
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "SSL_accept error = %d\n", SSL_get_error(ssl, ret));
        return -1;
    }


    char filename[BUFFSIZE] = {0};
    if (recv(connfd, filename, BUFFSIZE, 0) == -1)
    {
        perror("Can't receive filename");
        exit(1);
    }

    FILE *fp = fopen("output.txt", "wb");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        perror("Can't open file");
        exit(1);
    }
    char addr[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
    printf("Start receive file: %s from %s\n", filename, inet_ntop(AF_INET, &clientaddr.sin_addr, addr, INET_ADDRSTRLEN));
    writefile(ssl, fp);
    printf("Receive Success, NumBytes = %d\n", total);

    SSL_free(ssl);
    SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
    fclose(fp);
    close(connfd);
    return 0;
}

void writefile(SSL *ssl, FILE *fp)
{
    ssize_t n;
    char buff[MAX_LINE] = {0};
    clock_t t; 
    t = clock(); 
    while ((n = SSL_read(ssl, buff, sizeof(buff))) > 0)
    {
        total += n;
        if (n == -1)
        {
            perror("Receive File Error");
            exit(1);
        }

        if (fwrite(buff, sizeof(char), n, fp) != n)
        {
            perror("Write File Error");
            exit(1);
        }
        memset(buff, 0, MAX_LINE);
    }
    t = clock() - t; 
    double time_taken = ((double)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC; // in seconds 
    printf("%f seconds to receive data \n", time_taken); 
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Why do you use `strlen(sendline)` instead of `n`? Why do you declare `total` in `main` but don't really use it? Why is `sendfile` a `void` function? So many questions.

Comment: total is a global variable and it is used in main.
strlen(sendline) has the same value of n. sendfile is a void function because it only has to read the file and send its contents.

Comment: And how many bytes actually got sent with your line `if (send(sockfd, buff, BUFFSIZE, 0) == -1)`?  `send()` can and will send only a portion of your request, especially with TCP sockets.  Your code doesn't handle partial results on either sending or receiving data.  And you shouldn't be using `send()` and `recv()` on the socket file descriptor anyway if you want to send encrypted data via OpenSSL - that will just send your data over the connection exactly as if you hadn't used OpenSSL at all - and it will cause the peer to have problems with the plaintext when it was expecting encrypted data.

Comment: I understood the problem. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The receiver calls `recv()` on `connfd` after this file descriptor has been given to the `ssl` connection, so there is nothing more to be read on the ssl connection.